# JS Function to resolve collision between circle and rectangle

Tags: javascript, game-physics, game-development, collision, 2d-games

I'm making a top down 2D game, with circles for players. I've been trying to write a function to take in details about a collision after it has been detected (and before it has been rendered) to get the appropriate coordinates to move to to resolve the collision, but it has problems when the player collides with the CORNER of the rect. The player will clip into the rect when correcting, and bounce around on the corner as long as multiple directions are held. Any and all fixes are very helpful, as my trig is rusty and I've been trying at this for far too long. so far I have:

player: circle representing the player AFTER COLLISION

object/collider: object/collider the the player collided with

oldCoords: player coords BEFORE COLLISION

input: json structure representing player movement input on both axis with values from -1 to 1, ex. {x: 0, y: 1}

```
    function resolvePlayerCollision(player, object, oldCoords, input, deltaTime){
      let solvedCoords;
      const collider = object.collider;
      const rectCorners = [
        {x: (collider.x - (collider.width / 2)), y: (collider.y + (collider.height / 2))},
        {x: (collider.x + (collider.width / 2)), y: (collider.y + (collider.height / 2))},
        {x: (collider.x - (collider.width / 2)), y: (collider.y - (collider.height / 2))},
        {x: (collider.x + (collider.width / 2)), y: (collider.y - (collider.height / 2))}
      ];
    
      const nearestPoint = nearestPointOnRect(player, collider);
      let cornerCollision = false;
    
      for(let corner of rectCorners){
        if((corner.x == nearestPoint.x) && (corner.y == nearestPoint.y)) cornerCollision = true;
      }
      
      if(cornerCollision == true){
        // Corner collision
        solvedCoords = oldCoords;
    
        // Ignore input on the axis closest to the collider if both axis are being input
        let goodInput = input;
        console.log('\n', goodInput.x, goodInput.y)
        if((input.x != 0) && (input.y != 0)){
          const Xdistance = Math.abs(collider.x - player.x);
          const Ydistance = Math.abs(collider.y - player.y);
    
          goodInput[(Xdistance > Ydistance)? 'y' : 'x'] = 0;
        }
        
        // Calculate direction to player
        const directionToPlayer = (90 + (Math.sign(player.y - collider.y) * 45)) * -1 * Math.sign(player.x - collider.x) / 180 * Math.PI;
        
        if(goodInput.x == 1){
          // Right
          const solvedAngle = Math.sin(directionToPlayer);
          
          solvedCoords.x += deltaTime * Constants.playerSpeed * Math.sin(solvedAngle + (Math.PI / 2));
          solvedCoords.y += Math.sign(player.y - collider.y) * deltaTime * Constants.playerSpeed * Math.cos(solvedAngle);
        } else if(goodInput.x == -1){
          // Left
          const solvedAngle = Math.sin(directionToPlayer);
          
          solvedCoords.x += deltaTime * Constants.playerSpeed * Math.sin(solvedAngle);
          solvedCoords.y += Math.sign(player.y - collider.y) * deltaTime * Constants.playerSpeed * Math.cos(solvedAngle); 
        } else if(goodInput.y == 1){
          // Up
          const solvedAngle = Math.tan(directionToPlayer + (Math.PI / 2));
    
          solvedCoords.x += deltaTime * Constants.playerSpeed * Math.sin(solvedAngle);
          solvedCoords.y += deltaTime * Constants.playerSpeed * Math.cos(solvedAngle); 
        } else{
          // Down
          const solvedAngle = Math.tan(directionToPlayer);
          
          solvedCoords.x += deltaTime * Constants.playerSpeed * Math.sin(solvedAngle);
          solvedCoords.y += deltaTime * Constants.playerSpeed * Math.cos(solvedAngle);
        }
      } else {
        // Side collision
        solvedCoords = {x: player.x, y: player.y};
    
        // Get axis and dimension of penetration
        const axisOfPenetration = (Math.abs(collider.x - player.x) > Math.abs(collider.y - player.y))? 'x' : 'y';
        const dimensionOfPenetration = (axisOfPenetration == 'x')? 'width' : 'height';
        
        // Solve the collision on the axis of penetration
        solvedCoords[axisOfPenetration] = reverseClamp(player[axisOfPenetration], (collider[axisOfPenetration] - (collider[dimensionOfPenetration] / 2) - Constants.playerRadius), (collider[axisOfPenetration] + (collider[dimensionOfPenetration] / 2) + Constants.playerRadius));
    
        console.log(solvedCoords)
      }
      
      return solvedCoords;
    }
```

and in the player class:

```
     move(deltaTime, collidables){
        // Freeze input
        const input = this.input;
    
        // Return if there is no movement input
        if((input.x == 0) && (input.y == 0)) return;
    
        // Calculate movement direction (I don't fully understand how this works, and should probably figure it out)
        this.dir = (Math.PI / 2) - Math.atan2(-input.y, input.x);
        
        // Move
        const oldX = this.x;
        const oldY = this.y;
        
        this.x += deltaTime * Constants.playerSpeed * Math.sin(this.dir);
        if(Math.abs(this.x) > (Constants.mapSize / 2)) this.x = oldX;
        
        this.y -= deltaTime * Constants.playerSpeed * Math.cos(this.dir);
        if(Math.abs(this.y) > (Constants.mapSize / 2)) this.y = oldY;
    
        const collision = getFirstPlayerCollision(this, collidables);
        
        if(collision != false){
          const solvedCoords = resolvePlayerCollision(this, collision, {x: oldX, y: oldY}, input, deltaTime);
    
          this.x = solvedCoords.x;
          this.y = solvedCoords.y;
          
          if(Math.abs(this.x) > (Constants.mapSize / 2)) this.x = oldX;
          if(Math.abs(this.y) > (Constants.mapSize / 2)) this.y = oldY;
        }
      }
```

*The code is also unoptimized, so if there's something blatantly unnecesary please include that in your answer, thanks (:*